# Why does editing my .swift source code on my macbook remotely from Visual Studio on Windows PC remove permission for group & everyone of file on mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, file, networking, file-permissions

Specifically, Visual Studio changes file permission shown by bash ls -l on macbook
from:

> -rwxrwxrwx            read write exec for owner, group, everyone

to:

> -rw_______        only owner read write

TEXT EDITOR...
Problem does NOT occur if I use NOTEPAD on PC and not VISUAL STUDIO.

CONNECTION...
The Windows PC and macbook are connected by Ethernet peer-to-peer.

COMPUTERS...
With same Windows PC, this works on older macbook but not on newer macbook.